# XCode5 can't install app on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5

I successfully installed the app several times. Suddenly, I got this message "My App" exited unexpectedly, lost connection. This happens with iOS 6.x and 7 . I already tried deleting app manually from simulator, resetting, clean, quit, restart, everything ...

Any advice?

Comment: The app can be installed and executed on the device without problems

Comment: Do other projects build on the simulator?

Comment: I've been having this problem recently too, but quitting the simulator (and sometimes Xcode as well) has always fixed it for me.

Comment: AJak, yes other projects build fine. In fact, the answer I'm going to post  is related to running a different project. Thanks

Comment: I have this problem with all of my projects. The only solution for me is to quit Xcode and reopen. Extremely annoying. Doesn't anyone else have this issue? I have both Xcode 4 and 5 installed and it never happens when running an app from Xcode 4.

Comment: Generally just quitting the xCode Simulator and running the project solves this problem. For me this has become annoying because I have to quit run the Xcode project every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a "Fix" for this. After trying everything and getting the same error on "My App", I opened and tried to run "My App 2". "My App 2" ran fine, so I went back to "My App", tried again and this time everything worked fine. Crazy

Comment: :( - I hopefully opened another app and ran it, got excited when it worked, but then I went back to the project that was having problems and it behaved no differently.

Answer (score 3):

In the iOS Simulator menu, do "Reset Content & Settings".  If that doesn't fix it, reboot your computer.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` fixes the issue for me (reference: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4))